# How would I make a login screen using a .env file?

Tags: javascript, html, environment-variables

I'm trying to make a login screen and use a password from a .env file.

This is the code I have tried/made.

```html
<script>
  const submitURLChange = document.getElementById('submitURLChange');
  const urlChangeBox = document.getElementById('pass');
  function changeURL(response, urlPath) {
    const user = document.getElementById('login');
    const pass = document.getElementById('pass');
    console.log(pass.value+' -- '+process.env.password)
    if pass.value === (process.env.password) {
      location.replace("https://google.com"); // using a google redirect for testing
      location.reload();
    }
  }
  submitURLChange.addEventListener('click', changeURL);
</script>
```

I feel like I did something wrong here, let me know of a fix.

Comment: You shouldn't do password checking on the client side, that's a server side thing

Comment: BTW how is it you are using process.env in a browser ?

Comment: Could I get an article for that? I'd like to do this through env.

Comment: @36ve Unsure, that's just what I've seen be possible and it's been used in other projects.

Comment: Regarding your reply yo @36ve . Could you share some projects you have seen doing this (some links/repos)?

Answer (score 3):

Values in `.env` files are not accessible from the browser. You need some sort of server side logic

Comment: Could I get an example/article?

Comment: @Bee process.env is part of NodeJS. Browser Javascript has no access to client file as this is a security issue

Comment: [link](https://stackabuse.com/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-with-dotenv/#:~:text=%2F%60)

Rather than asking for the article, it will be helpful for us to help you if you can show us what are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm getting now, I'm trying to find the way to communicate from the browser to script/NodeJs. Not finding anything with google searches.

I'll take a look at the above article and get back to this post once I can make the edits.

Comment: @Bee do you have a server side(nodejs) application running?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis I don't really have anything on the serverside as of now trying to figure out how to connect client and server currently.

Comment: Search about REST apis . A rest api allows a client to send requests (in your case your client side javascript/ your HTML page) to the server and then the server send back a response to the client